# Django mandatory Decimal field

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have some problem with django, i have a field that i need to convert to mandatory:

```
slice_thickness = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=""
, help_text="Nominal slice thickness, in mm")
```

when i try to set `null=False, blank=False` give me this error:

*File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1559, in to_python*
*params={'value': value},*
*django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value must be a decimal number."]*

I also tried:

```
 slice_thickness =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False, default=Decimal('0.00')
                                          , help_text="Nominal slice thickness, in mm")

def slice_thickness_decimal(self):
        return str(Decimal(self.slice_thickness))
```

but it generates the same error.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by " i have a field that i need to convert to mandatory:`"?

Comment: ```null=True, blank=True``` to ```null=False, blank=False```